# Binding of Type&& (rvalue reference) to modifiable lvalues and

Tags: c++, c++11

Deepening my C++ knowledge, and found excellent article that explains Rvalue references http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx (article is somewhat dated, published in 2009).

In the article there are few lines of that should error out

```
// original
   string&& i = modifiable_lvalue;         // Line 26

    string&& j = const_lvalue;              // Line 27 - ERROR

    string&& k = modifiable_rvalue();       // Line 28

    string&& l = const_rvalue();            // Line 29 - ERROR
```

However, in Visual Studio 2012 `string&& i = modifiable_lvalue;         // Line 26 - ERROR` also errors out  !!!

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to
>   'std::string &&'

According to the article

> modifiable rvalue reference, Type&& , is willing to bind to modifiable
>   lvalues and modifiable rvalues

Which is exactly should have happened on line 26. So why am I getting the error ??
Thanks !

EDIT: Found very interesting article pertaining to this topic: http://web.archive.org/web/20120529225102/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/move-it-with-rvalue-references/#fn:insertionsort. Future reader might find it helpful.

Comment: @nosid: No, the code in the question is a verbatim copy of the code in the article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The article is wrong, an rvalue-reference cannot bind to an lvalue. Now there is the concept of reference collapsing (that does not apply here) that allows something similar in a template argument:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& x);
```

The argument `x` can bind to either an lvalue or rvalue, but when it binds to an lvalue it is not an *rvalue-reference*, rather the deduced type `T` is `U&`, and the two references in `U& &&` collapse into just the lvalue reference, so the argument is of type `U&` (with the *rvalue-reference* being dropped out). This is usually called *universal reference*.

Again, this does **not** apply to the code that you quote from the article, that is incorrect.

Note that the article was written in 2009, and the standard draft at the time might have the behavior described in the article. There were a few changes from 2009 to 2011 when the current standard was finally accepted.

Comment: +1. I believe there *was* a time (= version of the standard draft) when r-value refs could bind to l-values as well. So it might simply be based on that version.

Comment: So, basically non-const Type&& can bind to only modifiable rvalues.
While const Type&& can bind to const and non-const rvalues. On top of that `string& c = modifiable_rvalue();` is also true - i.e Type& can bind to mod. rvalue.

Comment: @newprint: The last part is not true, a non-const lvalue reference can only bind to a non-const lvalue: `Type&` cannot bind to a non-const rvalue. The simple rules: const reference can bind const or non-const values of the same category (l/rvalue). Non-const reference can only bind non-const values of the same category. Finally the exception: const lvalue-references are special and they can bind to rvalues, but it doesn't really... a temporary variable is created from the rvalue and the const lvalue reference binds to the rvalue.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  A const lvalue-reference can bind sometimes directly to an rvalue, a temporary may not be created.  Likewise sometimes a temporary may be created to indirectly bind an rvalue-reference.  See 8.5.3.

Comment: @user1131467: You are right on the const-lvalue-reference. I prefer the less imprecise wording above as it makes the requirement obvious: binding a const lvalue-reference to an rvalue *requires* an available copy constructor (yes, the copy will be elided in 99% of the cases, but the copy constructor must be available). Regarding a temporary being created when binding an rvalue-reference to an rvalue, I am not sure about it (haven't quite dug into 8.5.3, but intuitively that would require the availability of a copy-constructor or move-constructor which I believe not to be the case)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: _"binding a const lvalue-reference to an rvalue requires an available copy constructor"_: Incorrect sorry.  Counterexample: `struct X { X(const X&) = delete; }; X&& f(); const X& x = f();`.

Comment: @user1131467: Confusing as it might look an *rvalue-reference* is an *lvalue*, not an *rvalue*. Change the declaration above to be `X f();` and see the results.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas If `string& c = modifiable_rvalue();` is false (i.e doesn't fall into any of the rules you presented), why Visual Studio doesn't complain ? Is it bug in the compiler or MS unfinished implementation of C++11 ? Edit: Out of curiosity, I also compiled with Intel C++ Compiler 13.0 - no errors !!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Dude, you're confused. The function call expression `f()` in my first example is an xvalue, which is also an rvalue - it is not an lvalue.  The direct binding requirement also applies to class prvalues, which are also rvalues, so for example: `struct X { X(const X&) = delete; }; X f(); const X& x = f();`.  The function call expression `f()` is now a class prvalue, which is an rvalue, and it is directly bound to the lvalue-reference, a temporary is not created to indirectly bind, and no copy constructor is required.

Comment: @user1131467: It seems that the rules have changed quite a bit since C++03. After reading 8.5.3 in C++11 standard it is clear that you are right and that no copy constructor is required. On the other hand, in C++03 the standard did require the availability of the copy constructor.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: _Change the declaration above to be X f(); and see the results._: Here is a full example including a definition of `f`: `struct X { X(){}; X(const X&) = delete; }; X f() { return {}; }; const X& x = f();`.  No copy constructor required, the reference is directly bound to the prvalue `f()`.  Your confusion comes from the return statement, which is copy-initialization if not with `braced-init-list`, but has nothing to do with the reference binding.

Comment: @user1131467: No, my confusion is not having read the section in C++11, as I already told you. The C++03, with which I am more familiar (if nothing else for having known it for a much longer time) requires a copy in the example you provided. The reference is directly bound to an lvalue or a temporary is (possibly) created for an rvalue, but (8.5.3/5b2): *The constructor that would be used to make the copy shall be callable whether or not the copy is
actually done.* I have read the C++11 standard and that has changed and now the reference binds directly to the class-rvalue.

Comment: @newprint: C++ compilers are allowed to compile ill-formed programs as an extension.  MSVC supports binding of non-const lvalue-references to rvalues as such an extension.  This is a source of controversy and complaint again Microsoft, but they are not considering changing it because it would break old Windows-specific code that depends on this extension.

Answer (score 2):

The article is incorrect. You need to convert it to an rvalue ref explicitly, either with a `static_cast<std::string&&>` or more idiomatically, with std::move():

```
std::string&& i = std::move( modifiable_lvalue );
```

This code tells the compiler (and the reader!) that you're promising to be done with `modifiable_lvalue`.